# From which function discount coupon value is getting subtracted from Subtotal?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to know the function name from where coupon value is getting subtracted from subtotal or any table used?

I want to change the cart Subtotal value, if coupon code is applied then it should take MRP not selling price.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can find coupon code post action at

app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

```
   /**
     * Initialize coupon
     */
    public function couponPostAction()
    {
      /** Some code **/
        try {
            $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
            $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;

            $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();

            if ($codeLength) {
                if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode))
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(
                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode))
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Coupon code was canceled.'));
            }

        }
      /** Some code **/

}
```

2. The tables are `salesrule_coupon` and `salesrule`.
3. `checkout_cart_save_after` event help you to change the sub total based on condition.
4. Recommended not to edit in core module, create a new module and override.

Comment: thanks a lot - You can give me the code for event checkout_cart_save_after and how to override?

Comment: I can suggest/help you, but i can not provide the code ....:)

Comment: yes, info provided was a great help. I will try to implement and soon approve your answer.